# Powershell Base64 String to Bytes

Tags: string, powershell, soap, base64, arrays

I am trying to convert a File with Powershell to a Base64 encoded Byte Array which is required by a webservice. How can i do that?

My current approach is to :

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$scriptpath/dummy.txt")
$base64String =[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($content))

$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri _____.wsdl
//... set up proxy-objects


$namespace = $proxy.GetType().Namespace
$soapObject= new-object ("$namespace.customType") 
$soapObject.byteArray = base64String
```

The last line will not work, since base64String is not a byte array. Unfortunately I is required to be a byte-array and i have no access to the Server-Side.

Using the XML-Notation i simply can put the Base64Encoded String directly. But how to do with powershell?

```
<customType><byteArray>anyBase64String</byteArray></customType>
```

Comment: What is `soapObject` here? I'd expect that if it's expecting a byte array, then you should be able to provide the byte array and the proxy will convert it to base64.

Comment: That's it! As simple as just pasting the raw data.... For completeness I added the soapObject initialization. If you put it to an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `soapObject.byteArray` is expecting a byte array, I'd expect to just be able to give it the array - let the proxy perform the encoding in base64. So:

```
$soapObject.byteArray = content
```

No need for `base64String` at all.